# hibernate: how to fetch child collection at the time of parent

Tags: hibernate

I have casemaster(DLawCaseMaster - parent) class and casemaster history (DLawCaseMasterH - child) class. I have situation where I need parent and child collection both.

DLawCaseMaster.java

```
public class DLawCaseMaster implements java.io.Serializable {
    //.....
    private Set<DLawCaseMasterH> DLawCaseMasterHs = new HashSet<DLawCaseMasterH>(0);
    //.....

    public Set<DLawCaseMasterH> getDLawCaseMasterHs() {
        return this.DLawCaseMasterHs;
    }

    public void setDLawCaseMasterHs(Set<DLawCaseMasterH> DLawCaseMasterHs) {
        this.DLawCaseMasterHs = DLawCaseMasterHs;
    }
}
```

DLawCaseMaster.hbm.xml

```
<set inverse="true" name="DLawCaseMasterHs">
  <key>
    <column name="CASE_ID" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.law.beans.DLawCaseMasterH"/>
</set>
```

DLawCaseMasterH.java

```
public class DLawCaseMasterH  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private DLawCaseMasterHId id;
    private DLawCaseMaster DLawCaseMaster;

    public void setId(DLawCaseMasterHId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public DLawCaseMaster getDLawCaseMaster() {
        return this.DLawCaseMaster;
    }

    public DLawCaseMaster getDLawCaseMaster() {
        return this.DLawCaseMaster;
    }

    public void setDLawCaseMaster(DLawCaseMaster DLawCaseMaster) {
        this.DLawCaseMaster = DLawCaseMaster;
    }
}
```

DLawCaseMasterH.hbm.xml

```
<composite-id class="com.law.beans.DLawCaseMasterHId" name="id">
  <key-property name="historyId" type="long">
    <column name="HISTORY_ID"/>
  </key-property>
  <key-property name="caseId" type="long">
    <column name="CASE_ID"/>
  </key-property>
</composite-id>
<many-to-one class="com.law.beans.DLawCaseMaster" fetch="select" insert="false" name="DLawCaseMaster" update="false">
  <column name="CASE_ID" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

I have tried following strategy but each time it returns blank list.

```
public static List<DLawCaseMaster> getCaseListWithHistory(long userID, Date asOnDate, Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    List<DLawCaseMaster> list = new ArrayList<DLawCaseMaster>();
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DLawCaseMaster.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("disposalDate"));

        if (asOnDate == null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.between("disposalDate", fromDate, toDate));
        } else {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("disposalDate", asOnDate));
        }
        criteria.setFetchMode("DLawUserMaster", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
        criteria.setFetchMode("DLawAdvocateMaster", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
        criteria.setFetchMode("DLawCourtMaster", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
        criteria.setFetchMode("DLawClientMaster", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
        criteria.setFetchMode("DLawCaseTypeMaster", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
        criteria.setFetchMode("DLawStageMaster", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
        // PROBLEM LINE HERE
criteria.createCriteria("DLawCaseMasterHs").add(Restrictions.eq("DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));
// PROBLEM LINE HERE

        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("caseId"));

        list = criteria.list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Message : " + e.getMessage());
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        return list;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

If I remove **PROBLEM LINE HERE** it will return list with 3 records but when access DLawCaseMasterHs it throws an exception. In short it does not have any data.

Can any one guide me to fetch children while fetching parent... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this ??

```
criteria.createAlias("DLawCaseMasterHs", "dlawCase", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("dlawCase.userId", userID));
```

Comment: I have tried this but result is empty list. criteria.createAlias("DLawCaseMasterHs", "dlawCase", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("dlawCase.DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));

Comment: Sorry...it is working fine but instead of returning 3 record of case master it returns 6 record. So I have done below changes                                                             criteria.createAlias("DLawCaseMasterHs", "dlawCase", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("dlawCase.DLawUserMaster.userId", userID));            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);        I regret for previous comment. Thanks a lot @The Suresh Atta